# Receiving an undefined error when submitting a form in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, events, form-submit

I am creating a form element within my React app. When I try to save the form value in a const, I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined". Here is a snippet of my component:

```
export default class LookupTag extends React.Component {
    state= {
        error: undefined
    };

    getProductData = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const upc = e.target.elements.option.value;
        const error = this.props.getProductData(upc);

        this.setState(() => ({ error }));
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
                <form onSubmit={this.getProductData}>
                    <input type='text' name='upc'/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Please note that I am using a babel plugin called "transform-class-properties" which allows me to remove the constructor entirely (aka it is not a binding problem). The specific error is referencing the line where I set "const upc = e.target.elements.option.value;". I have also tried just using "e.target.value" but the same error occurs. Any ideas would be appreciated! Please let me know if you need any more info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an element `option`, so `e.target.elements.option` will give you `undefined`, and trying to access `value` on that will give rise to your error.

`e.target.elements.upc.value` will work.

```
getProductData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const upc = e.target.elements.upc.value;
    const error = this.props.getProductData(upc);

    this.setState(() => ({ error }));
};
```